# Testcase for Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, automated-tests

Question on writing TestCase for SQLite.

I tried following to write a test, but it breaks down.

The Android Studio showed error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException on the two error lines in the following code. Maybe someone can show me where it goes wrong.

```
public class DeviceDatabase {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DeviceSQLiteHelper dbHelper;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public DeviceDatabase(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DeviceSQLiteHelper(context);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    /**
     *  close sqlite database
     */
    public void close() {
        db.close();
    }


    /**
     * Create new device
     * @param
     */
    public boolean createDevice(String bt_name, String bt_addr, String bdx_name) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DeviceSQLiteHelper.BT_NAME, bt_name);
        contentValues.put(DeviceSQLiteHelper.BT_ADDR, bt_addr);
        contentValues.put(DeviceSQLiteHelper.BDX_NAME, bdx_name);
        // Insert into DB
        long result = db.insert(DeviceSQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result != 0 )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
...
```

The Test class with a MockContext. Honestly I don't know it can be used this way or not.

```
public class DeviceListControlTest {
    String bt_addr = "00:01:02:03:03:08";

    public DeviceDatabase mDeviceDatabase;

    public MockContext mMockContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // need mock context
        mMockContext = new MockContext();
        mDeviceDatabase = new DeviceDatabase(mMockContext);   // error
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateDevice() throws Exception {
        mDeviceDatabase.createDevice("Hamburg", bt_addr, "HamburgBT");
        List<DeviceName> deviceNameList;
        deviceNameList = mDeviceDatabase.getDevices();

        boolean result = checkItem(deviceNameList, bt_addr);
        assertThat(true, is(equalTo(result)));
    }

    ....
```

Comment: i hope your DeviceDatabase method is not in onCreate or onUpgrade?

Comment: no. I put more code now in the question

Answer (score 0):

When you run Unit tests on your machine (not on Android device/emulator itself) stub version of Android SDK is used which throws `UnsupportedOperationException` on each call to any method.

You have 2 (good) options:

1. Run tests on Android device itself (see Instrumentation tests)
2. Use Robolectric

Comment: Thanks, I will check the suggestions.